# Read a csv file into one String

Tags: java, string, csv, file

I want to essentially read the contents of csv file and want to input into one string to return. I tried this and it doesnt quite work:

```
File file = new File(aaa.csv);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
BufferReader bw = new BufferReader(fw);
String s;
while (bw.readLine() != null) {
        s += (bw.readLine());
    }
    fw.close();
```

Is there a easier solution to reading csv file into string that works?

Comment: Is this really csv-specific or are you simply asking how to read a whole file into a string?

Comment: what doesnt work about it? what error are you getting?

Comment: Generally, I would advise to do proper OOP, and also to use NIO. So more something like this: https://gist.github.com/Zabuzard/f0f4e9ee47ef576e46a21a8c224743d8 (I had this snippet lingering around)

Comment: This code does not compile.  `BufferedReader` has a typo (you wrote `BufferReader`), `BufferedReader` cannot be used with `FileWriter` (it needs to be `FileReader`).  Also, `new File(aaa.csv)` will not compile because you did not wrap the parameter in double quotes.  Post your _actual_ code.

Comment: "It doesn't quite work" isnt a working problem description. See [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Or well, please do a bit of research. The question "how do I read a text file into a string" is a solved problem. Remember: ANY basic problem you can think of ... it has been asked here (and elsewhere) before, and many answers were documented.

Answer (score 5):

To read the entire file, assuming Java 11 and above, you can simply do:

```
String content = Files.readString(Paths.get("aaa.csv"));
```

note that if the file is very large memory becomes a problem.

Comment: `String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("aa.csv")));` for Java 7+

Comment: @Eritrean Please explicitly specify the encoding on the constructor, `new String(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, unless you are on Java 18 or newer (_JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default_). Otherwise you will likely mess up the content.